# ¿Por qué cuando creo un contendor desde compose file no tiene mi proyecto pero si lo creo desde docker desktop si lo tiene?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Tengo el siguiente dockerfile

```
    FROM php:7.3.33-apache
    
    RUN a2enmod rewrite
    
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
            zlib1g-dev \
            libicu-dev \
            libxml2-dev \
            libpq-dev \
            libzip-dev \
            libpng-dev \
            && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip intl xmlrpc soap opcache gd \
            && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd
    
    
    RUN apt-get update -y 
    
    # Add Node 18 LTS
    RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash -- \
        && apt-get install -y nodejs \
        && apt-get autoremove -y
    
    COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
    
    COPY  docker/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
    COPY  docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    
    ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1
    
    COPY  . /var/www/html/
    WORKDIR /var/www/html/
    
    RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html  \
        && composer install  && composer dumpautoload
```

al momento de hacer mi build todo genial pero llegamos a un punto confuso para mi y es al momento de generar un contenedor, si yo genero el contendor desde docker desktop ya este contendor viene con mi proyecto includo pero si creo una un servicio desde compose file simplemente es como si mi contenedor se creara sin el proyecto, mi compose file es el siguiente:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    image: catastro
    restart: always
    networks:
      - app-network
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/
networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```